# @font-face rule in CSS files in Synmfony 2 with Assetic

Tags: css, symfony, fonts, assetic

I'm looking for including fonts from CSS files in Symfony using Assetic. The issue is the browser fails to load these fonts.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Corbert'; /*a name to be used later*/
src:    url('fonts/Corbert-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
        url('fonts/Corbert-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Corbert-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

My path structure is

```
...  
+-src/  
| +-MyCompany/  
|   +-MyBundle/  
|     +-Resources/  
|       +-public/  
|         +-css/  
|           +-fonts/
```

My path linking the CSS files is

[image: path into css file]

[image]

[image]
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to access those files?

Comment: Seem that point to the correct resource, you must fix the 403 error: a permission error

Comment: I fixed the 403 error. But I still get errors. It's all up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution :

Just put in your Document.html.twig where you link your css files:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Corbert'; 
  src:    url({{asset('fonts/Corbert-Regular.otf')}}) format('opentype'), 
    url({{asset('fonts/Corbert-Regular.woff')}}) format('woff'),
    url({{asset('fonts/Corbert-Regular.otf')}}) format('truetype');
  }
</style>
```

Indeed if you put that in the css file, symfony doesn't seem to recognize the code. It's the same for the picture :

```
<style type="text/css">
  body, html{
    background-image:url({{ asset('images/wallpaper.png') }});
  }
<style>
```

Nice Week-end !

Comment: Thanks for this! Really aggravating that there is no documentation on this bug anywhere. By the by, you should check this as the solution. Will make it easier for others to find. :)